# Can a block cipher be used to encrypt wireless communications?

Tags: block-cipher, cbc-mac

Would it be possible to use a block cipher such as CBC in order to encrypt a wireless communication? For example, could I use CBC-MAC, on each block, for encryption for WiFi?

Comment: A block cipher with block size of n bits under a user given key is simply a bijective mapping of n bits to n bits. The result of encryption can be transmitted in any kind of channels (including on paper via normal mail). Thus I don't yet understand why "wireless communications" would make any difference as far as the security of encryption processing is concerned.

Comment: CBC isn't a block cipher.

Comment: Your question is like asking whether machine language can be used to build a self-driving car.  The answer is yes, but I hope you can see the problem with the question—it leaves out all the critically important stuff in between the primitives and the desired goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can encrypt wireless communication *using* a block cipher in a specific mode of operation to provide *confidentiality*. Transport modes also require *integrity* and *authentication* to protect against active attacks such as man-in-the-middle attacks.

CBC is however not a block cipher, and neither is CBC-MAC. CBC is a *block cipher mode of operation* used to provide confidentiality while CBC-MAC is a *message authentication code* used to provide integrity and authenticity. These constructs *use* a block cipher such as AES to provide this kind of functionality.

AES (and DES, 3DES, blowfish, Serpent, threefish etc. etc.) *are* block ciphers. They need to be used with a mode of operation such as CBC to provide confidentiality of messages; they cannot provide such functionality without a mode of operation. A mode of operation also requires an IV or nonce if the key is ever reused. In transport protocols the keys are usually kept for the duration of a session.

WPA2 may use the [CCMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#Encryption_protocol) which combines AES in CTR (counter) mode for encryption and AES in CBC-MAC mode for integrity and authentication of messages.

Note that the protection of messages is just *part* of the protocol. Entity authentication and session key establishment require additional cryptographic primitives (a cryptographic primitive is an algorithm such as AES or RSA that is used within a larger scheme).

Comment: Thanks @maartenbodewes, so would it be correct to say that CBC-MAC could not take the place of AES for WPA2?

Comment: AES is used *within* CBC-MAC. So that statement would not make sense. CBC-MAC requires a block cipher to operate, and that block cipher is usually AES (although any secure block cipher will do, preferably one with a 128 bits block size such as AES).

Comment: I had meant replace AES in CTR mode with CBC-MAC (should have reread the comment before I posted it)

Comment: CTR mode is used to provide confidentiality of messages, CBC-MAC provides integrity and authenticity. As they provide different functionality altogether, one can not replace the other.